# How to generate the power set of a set in Scala

Tags: scala, set, powerset

I have a Set of items of some type and want to generate its power set.

I searched the web and couldn't find any Scala code that adresses this specific task.

This is what I came up with. It allows you to restrict the cardinality of the sets produced by the length parameter.

```
def power[T](set: Set[T], length: Int) = {
   var res = Set[Set[T]]()
   res ++= set.map(Set(_))

   for (i <- 1 until length)
      res = res.map(x => set.map(x + _)).flatten

   res
   }
```

This will not include the empty set. To accomplish this you would have to change the last line of the method simply to res + Set()

Any suggestions how this can be accomplished in a more functional style?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Notice that if you have a set `S` and another set `T` where `T = S ∪ {x}` (i.e. `T` is `S` with one element added) then the powerset of `T` -  `P(T)` - can be expressed in terms of `P(S)` and `x` as follows:

```
P(T) = P(S) ∪ { p ∪ {x} | p ∈ P(S) }
```

That is, you can **define the powerset recursively** (notice how this gives you the size of the powerset for free - i.e. adding 1-element doubles the size of the powerset). So, you can do this tail-recursively in scala as follows:

```
scala> def power[A](t: Set[A]): Set[Set[A]] = {
   |     @annotation.tailrec 
   |     def pwr(t: Set[A], ps: Set[Set[A]]): Set[Set[A]] =
   |       if (t.isEmpty) ps
   |       else pwr(t.tail, ps ++ (ps map (_ + t.head)))
   |
   |     pwr(t, Set(Set.empty[A])) //Powerset of ∅ is {∅}
   |   }
power: [A](t: Set[A])Set[Set[A]]
```

Then:

```
scala> power(Set(1, 2, 3))
res2: Set[Set[Int]] = Set(Set(1, 2, 3), Set(2, 3), Set(), Set(3), Set(2), Set(1), Set(1, 3), Set(1, 2))
```

It actually looks much nicer doing the same with a `List` (i.e. a recursive ADT):

```
scala> def power[A](s: List[A]): List[List[A]] = {
   |     @annotation.tailrec 
   |     def pwr(s: List[A], acc: List[List[A]]): List[List[A]] = s match {
   |       case Nil     => acc 
   |       case a :: as => pwr(as, acc ::: (acc map (a :: _)))
   |     }
   |     pwr(s, Nil :: Nil)
   |   }
power: [A](s: List[A])List[List[A]]
```

Answer (score 64):

Looks like no-one knew about it back in July, but there's a built-in method: `subsets`.

```
scala> Set(1,2,3).subsets foreach println
Set()
Set(1)
Set(2)
Set(3)
Set(1, 2)
Set(1, 3)
Set(2, 3)
Set(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 21):

Here's one of the more interesting ways to write it:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def powerSet[A](xs: List[A]) = xs filterM (_ => true :: false :: Nil)
```

Which works as expected:

```
scala> powerSet(List(1, 2, 3)) foreach println
List(1, 2, 3)
List(1, 2)
List(1, 3)
List(1)
List(2, 3)
List(2)
List(3)
List()
```

See for example [this discussion thread](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2009-August/064911.html) for an explanation of how it works.

(And as debilski notes in the comments, `ListW` also pimps `powerset` onto `List`, but that's no fun.)

Comment: I love that - my question would be, what else is `filterM` used for?

Comment: @oxbow_lakes You can for example do a three-way predicate filter. (`x => if ...` `None`/`Some(false)`/`Some(true)`). A single `None` would clear the whole input. But I guess there will be much more advanced usages with exotic monads I‘ve never heard of.

Comment: It is built-in by the way: `List(1, 2, 3).powerset`. :)

Comment: @oxbow_lakes: `let doYouLike it = fmap (== "y") $ putStr ("do you like " ++ show it ++ " (y/n)? ") >> getLine in filterM doYouLike ["scala", "haskell"]`

Comment: `filterM` and friends are quite useful for `M=[a]State[X, a]`. You could, for example, filter out repeats with: https://gist.github.com/3157243

Answer (score 15):

Use the built-in `combinations` function:

```
val xs = Seq(1,2,3)
(0 to xs.size) flatMap xs.combinations

// Vector(List(), List(1), List(2), List(3), List(1, 2), List(1, 3), List(2, 3),
// List(1, 2, 3))
```

Note, I cheated and used a `Seq`, because for reasons unknown, `combinations` is defined on `SeqLike`. So with a set, you need to convert to/from a `Seq`:

```
val xs = Set(1,2,3)
(0 to xs.size).flatMap(xs.toSeq.combinations).map(_.toSet).toSet

//Set(Set(1, 2, 3), Set(2, 3), Set(), Set(3), Set(2), Set(1), Set(1, 3), 
//Set(1, 2))
```

Comment: But with set, does it maintain lexicographic set?

Answer (score 3):

Can be as simple as:

```
def powerSet[A](xs: Seq[A]): Seq[Seq[A]] = 
  xs.foldLeft(Seq(Seq[A]())) {(sets, set) => sets ++ sets.map(_ :+ set)}
```

Recursive implementation:

```
def powerSet[A](xs: Seq[A]): Seq[Seq[A]] = {
  def go(xsRemaining: Seq[A], sets: Seq[Seq[A]]): Seq[Seq[A]] = xsRemaining match {
    case Nil => sets
    case y :: ys => go(ys, sets ++ sets.map(_ :+ y))
  }

  go(xs, Seq[Seq[A]](Seq[A]()))
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Kudos for foldLeft. I was looking for that implementation specifically. As an earlier commenter said, an explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

All the other answers seemed a bit complicated, here is a simple function:

```
    def powerSet (l:List[_]) : List[List[Any]] =
      l match {
       case Nil => List(List())
       case x::xs =>
         var a = powerSet(xs)
         a.map(n => n:::List(x)):::a
      }
```

so

```
    powerSet(List('a','b','c'))
```

will produce the following result

```
    res0: List[List[Any]] = List(List(c, b, a), List(b, a), List(c, a), List(a), List(c, b), List(b), List(c), List())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another (lazy) version... since we're collecting ways of computing the power set, I thought I'd add it:

```
def powerset[A](s: Seq[A]) =
  Iterator.range(0, 1 << s.length).map(i =>
    Iterator.range(0, s.length).withFilter(j =>
      (i >> j) % 2 == 1
    ).map(s)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple, recursive solution using a helper function:

```
def concatElemToList[A](a: A, list: List[A]): List[Any] = (a,list) match {
    case (x, Nil)                 => List(List(x))
    case (x, ((h:List[_]) :: t))  => (x :: h) :: concatElemToList(x, t)
    case (x, (h::t))              => List(x, h) :: concatElemToList(x, t)
}

def powerSetRec[A] (a: List[A]): List[Any] = a match {
    case Nil    => List()
    case (h::t) => powerSetRec(t) ++ concatElemToList(h, powerSetRec (t))
}
```

so the call of

```
powerSetRec(List("a", "b", "c"))
```

will give the result

```
List(List(c), List(b, c), List(b), List(a, c), List(a, b, c), List(a, b), List(a))
```

Comment: The empty set is missing from the results