# How to create all possible combinations from the elements of a list?

Tags: list, scala, for-loop

I have the following list:

```
List(a, b, c, d, e)
```

How to create all possible combinations from the above list?

I expect something like:

```
a
ab
abc
```

Comment: similar, except for sets: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11581175/770361

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Or you could use the `subsets` method. You'll have to convert your list to a set first though.

```
scala> List(1,2,3).toSet[Int].subsets.map(_.toList).toList
res9: List[List[Int]] = List(List(), List(1), List(2), List(3), List(1, 2), List(1, 3), List(2, 3), List(1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: I think it is really a clean approach to solve a complicated problem

Comment: Unless there is repetition in numbers.

Comment: Unless there are some heavy data structures in a list, making toSet (hashing) extremely slow.

Comment: Also, if you are trying to do do anything where ordering matters (checking for a part number that has a delimiter in the terms/etc), converting to a set will kill that information too

Comment: @ericpeters It says "combinations" not "permutations" so order is not important ;)

Answer (score 35):

```
def combine(in: List[Char]): Seq[String] = 
    for {
        len <- 1 to in.length
        combinations <- in combinations len
    } yield combinations.mkString
```

Comment: True. But the way I used to do this was waaaay hairier =P

Comment: The method `combinations(length)` defined  on `List`, gives you back a further iterator of sublists of limited length generated by combining the elements of the original list in any possible way. The for comprehension gives you all possible combinations for all lengths between 1 and the whole original list's length. The `combinations` assigned on the left of `<-` is one such possible shuffle. The `yield` gives you back a List of all those possible combinations. Check [the docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@combinations(n:Int):Iterator[Repr])

Answer (score 10):

```
def powerset[A](s: Set[A]) = s.foldLeft(Set(Set.empty[A])) { case (ss, el) => ss ++ ss.map(_ + el) }
```

Sounds like you need the [Power set](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Power_set#Scala).

Answer (score 10):

```
val xs = List( 'a', 'b' , 'c' , 'd' , 'e' )
(1 to xs.length flatMap (x => xs.combinations(x))) map ( x => x.mkString(""))
```

This should give you all the combination concatenated by empty String.