# Permutations with predicate Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, set, combinations

I am trying to solve combinations task in Scala. I have an array with repeated elements and I have to count the number of combinations which satisfy the condition a+b+c = 0. Numbers should not be repeated, if they are in different places it doesn`t count as a distinct combination.
So I turned my array into Set, so the elements would not repeat each other. Also, I have found about combinations method for sequences, but I am not really sure how to use it in this case. Also, I do not know where t put these permutations condition. 
Here is what I have for now:

```
var arr = Array(-1, -1, -2, -2, 1, -5, 1, 0, 1, 14, -8, 4, 5, -11, 13, 5, 7, -10, -4, 3, -6, 8, 6, 2, -9, -1, -4, 0)
val arrSet = Set(arr)
arrSet.toSeq.combinations(n)
```

I am new to Scala, so I would be really grateful for any advice!

Comment: did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109720/how-to-create-all-possible-combinations-from-the-elements-of-a-list?

Comment: I did. But I need to get combinations by some predicate, not all possible. So it wasn't really helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you need:

```
arr.distinct.combinations(3).filter(_.sum == 0).size
```

where:

- `distinct` removes the duplicates
- `combinations(n)` produces combinations of `n` elements
- `filter` filters them by keeping only those whose sum is 0
- `size` returns the total number of such combinations

P.S.: `arr` don't need to be a `var`. You should strive to never use `var` in Scala and stick to `val` as long as it's possible.

Comment: Thank you. It's a nice approach. Special thanks for the explanation :)