# How to make column pairs of map?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have some columns like

```
age | company | country | gender |
----------------------------------
 1  |   1     |  1      |  1     |
-----------------------------------
```

I want to create pairs like

- (age,company)
- (company,country)
- (country,gender)
- (company,gender)
- (age,gender)
- (age,country)
- (age,company,country)
- (company,country,gender)
- (age,country,gender)
- (age,company,gender)
- (age,company,country,gender)

Comment: I want to create these pairs because i have some other tables of two, three and four columns. I want to make these pairs and the value of these pairs is inserted in the tables according to columns pairs.

Comment: In controller in the form of map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An idiomatic approach to generating a powerset using `Set` collection method `subsets`,

```
implicit class groupCols[A](val cols: List[A]) extends AnyVal {
  def grouping() = cols.toSet.subsets.filter { _.size > 1 }.toList
}
```

Then

```
List("age","company","country","gender").grouping
```

delivers

```
List( Set(age, company), 
      Set(age, country), 
      Set(age, gender), 
      Set(company, country), 
      Set(company, gender), 
      Set(country, gender), 
      Set(age, company, country), 
      Set(age, company, gender), 
      Set(age, country, gender), 
      Set(company, country, gender), 
      Set(age, company, country, gender))
```

Note that the powerset includes the empty set and a set for each element in the original set, here we filter them out.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you can achieve this with tuples ([and this topic confirms it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722860/convert-a-scala-list-to-a-tuple)).
But what you are looking for is called `Power Set`.

Consider this piece of code:

```
object PowerSetTest extends Application {
  val ls = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
  println(power(ls.toSet).filter(_.size > 1))

  def power[A](t: Set[A]): Set[Set[A]] = {
    @annotation.tailrec
    def pwr(t: Set[A], ps: Set[Set[A]]): Set[Set[A]] =
      if (t.isEmpty) ps
      else pwr(t.tail, ps ++ (ps map (_ + t.head)))

    pwr(t, Set(Set.empty[A]))
  }
}
```

Running this gives you:

```
Set(Set(1, 3), Set(1, 2), Set(2, 3), Set(1, 2, 3, 4), Set(3, 4), Set(2, 4), Set(1, 2, 4), Set(1, 4), Set(1, 2, 3), Set(2, 3, 4), Set(1, 3, 4))
```

You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581175/how-to-generate-the-power-set-of-a-set-in-scala) for more information

Comment: There is already a `subsets` method for `Set`, which returns an `Iterator` over all subsets: `List(1,2,3,4).toSet.subsets.filter(_.size > 1).toSet`